# what device information is send to server when request is made from mobile to server

Tags: android, ios, web-services, api, mobile

While communicating to the server what device  specific data is appended in the payload or in the headers ? Does the device ip address gets send ? and how is the timestamp generated ?
thank you .

Comment: You dont know so much about networking right? If you use a HttpRequest class it will send some default headers, but you can always use a plain socket if you dont like it.

Comment: @Nanoc thanks for your reply ,yes i dont know much CN .i know that it send some default headers ...but i want to know what information does that headers has .

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, a HttpURLConnection will send this headers by default:

```
  User-Agent
  Host
  Accept
  Connection
```

Of course you can add more or modify the defaults as you need.

Hope this helps.